# Cross Domain Ajax request using Jquery and Ajax to get a value from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I am trying to make an Ajax request from my localhost to a php file in the server. As I am testing this, I am yet to do the real code in the PHP file. I just want the PHP file to get the posted value and echo the same. After getting the response from the PHP file, I want to store it in a div.

This works good when search.php in my localhost but throws an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mysite.com/search.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is the very simple PHP file on the server which echo back what is posted.

**HTML**

```
<form action='http://www.mysite.com/search.php' id='search-form' method='post'>  
    <input name='q' placeholder='Search' type='text' />
    <button id='search-button' type='submit'><span>Search</span></button>
  </form>
<div class="sample_code">Search Results</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
     $("#search-form").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
            term = $form.find('input[name="q"]').val(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            q: term
        });

        /* Put the results in a div */
        posting.done(function(data) {
            //var content = $(data).find('#content');
            $("#result").empty().append(data);
        });
    });
```

**A PHP file in the server to echo what is posted (search.php)**

```
    <?php

    $item = $_POST['term'];
    echo $item;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "jsonp", but it only supports GET method and is DOM-blocking.

Comment: Can you please give me a demo on this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for that post **ajax to your php** file **then** in php file use **curl** [a link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) that will call data from another website.

**echo curl response** and catch that data.

I have used this method.***Its working***.

Comment: No, First of all Ajax request from other sources than the server are not allowed. Javascript Ajax requests are bounded by Same Origin Policy. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy for further details.